# Error when running rails server loading error sqlite 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have been trying to run rails server for the last few days and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong... then I download ruby and its gems then I run rails server, I keep getting this message..

```
C:\Users\User>cd my_app

C:\Users\User\my_app>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb
:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler.rb
:134:in `require'
        from C:/Users/User/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

However I have `sqlite3` downloaded... 
con someone please let me know what to do ...thank you

Comment: Have you tried running `rake db:create` first?

Comment: No i haven't... how do i do that and what does it do? thanks

Comment: This is what came up when i tried it ...C:\Users\User\my_app>rake db:create
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
C:/Users/User/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/User/my_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.2/sqlite3_native
C:/Users/User/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/User/my_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Users\User\my_app>

Comment: I had similar problems trying to run Rails under Windows. They seemed endless.  I finally gave up, and I used [the Ruby Installer for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/). If you just need a working Rails installation, this might be the way to go.